# Call a POST web method through a Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, web-services

I'm trying to call an external web method via POST request during the execution of one of my workflows.

I set up the dictionary for the headers (I specify `Host`, `Content-Lenght`, `Content-Type` and `Authorization`, which is Basic), another dictionary for the parameters of the request and a third one containing that second dictionary used as the body. This is the only way I could find online on how to do it, taken from [this explanation](https://vgrem.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/call-http-web-service-create-operation.png) on steps 3 and 5.

It fails on execution, only giving me `InternalServerError` as response code. The simple POST request works without issues on Fiddler, so is not about wrong headers. I suppose I'm not building correctly my dictionaries, but as I said I can't find anything else apart from the previous image. Getting rid of the intermediate dictionary doesn't fix it either.

Do you know how to do this, or can you point me to some post where somebody explains it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to send your request to e.g. http://requestb.in/ to see if it looks the way it should?

Comment: That was actually a great idea, thanks. Now I know that Workflow is sending the body as JSON `{"parameters":{"foo":"bar"}}` instead of `foo=bar` which is what the web service needs. I cannot set it to send anything else than JSON-formed parameters instead of simple strings, and I cannot change what the web service expects, so I believe I've met a dead end...